# Remove p tags on images in Wordpress posts

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have a Wordpress site which posts have images and text within it. I want to remove the `<p>` tag on the images only.

html:

```
    <div class="col-md-12 ">
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>
```

This puts each piece into a `<p>` tag (images and text)

EDIT - what I attempted

html

```
<?php
        preg_match_all('/(<img [^>]*>)/', get_the_content(), $images);
        for( $i=0; isset($images[1]) && $i < count($images[1]); $i++ ) {
        echo $images[1][$i];
        }
?>
```

was able to pull the images out but that's it

Comment: Well, what did you already try to achieve that?

Comment: added it to my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to reinvent the wheel, [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/remove-paragraph-tags-from-around-images/) have a great example that is used by quite a few themes and devs:

```
function filter_ptags_on_images($content){
   return preg_replace('/<p>\s*(<a .*>)?\s*(<img .* \/>)\s*(<\/a>)?\s*<\/p>/iU', '\1\2\3', $content);
}

add_filter('the_content', 'filter_ptags_on_images');
```

Just apply this filter in your themes /functions.php

Comment: do i replace <?php the_content(); ?> with that code?

Comment: No, `<?php the_content(); ?>` is required to serve the content. You add this snippet of code to your themes **functions.php** file.

Comment: nice thats what I was looking for, way easier than the route I was going

Comment: You may need to save the posts / pages again to get it working!

Comment: I tried in 2023, it is nor working. The whole image element got removed by this snippet!